# Escaping " with \ on an HTML tag is not working

Tags: php, html, escaping, quotations

My final code looks like this:

```
<a href="/galleries/hairtinsels/hairtinsel/hairtinsels.jpg" rel="shadowbox[gallery]" title="Hair Tinsels, 24 Colour Choices, 36\" Long">
```

Note the `36\"` part - the `"` is escaped with a `\` so it should work, right? No, on shadowbox the title cuts off and just says:

Hair Tinsels, 24 Colour Choices, 36\

This is mind-boggling... any ideas?

This was escaped using `addslashes()` function in PHP - this gallery is generated by PHP looping through an array.

Comment: quote is to be escaped with special chars &quot;

Comment: Can you display the PHP that creates this link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the right escaping function for each context. And within HTML, you do need [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). The quote within double quotes should be `&quot;`. (The common C string escapes with the backslash don't work in HTML/XML/SGML.)

Quite commonly you need the charset parameter too:

```
 htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
 // and ENT_QUOTES just in case you had single quote attributes
```

Comment: Silly me. I was totally thinking in PHP mentality. Gotta switch back to XHTML.. Thanks!